# How was this possible?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In the mid-season finale, we finally get some answers to who Harrison Wells actually is and we finally see Flash and Reverse-Flash interact.

> However there's a scene in which S.T.A.R. Labs and the police team up to capture Reverse-Flash.  In the scene, Wells is seen interacting with him while he's trapped within their barrier.  We also see Reverse-Flash run up to Eddie and instead of killing him turn his attention to Joe, which is something Eddie actually addresses later in the episode.  At the end of the episode, we actually learn that Harrison Wells and Reverse-Flash are one in the same.  So, how was Wells able to have a full fledged conversation with himself in two different locations and how was he able to actually 'fight' himself inside the barrier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Reverse Flash setup the force field and the Reverse Flash inside as a hologram.  The Reverse Flash inside was just a recording playing back, while (Spoilers for *Flash* S1E15)

> Harrison Wells

was right there outside the force field watching things happen.  Then when the Reverse Flash attacked everyone, he simply moved fast enough to appear in two places at once.

Comment: Ok, so they are the same person, just one is from a later point in the future.

Comment: @Robert That's the 'simplest' explanation, at least given what we currently know.  It's *entirely* possible that we could be dealing with something more comic book-ey.  It could be an alternate Wells (or Barry!) from a parallel dimension!  It could be a future embittered and super-powered Eddie Thawne! Etc.  But this is the Occam's razor solution I can think of.

Comment: The alternate Barry makes me wonder as well, especially since it's also been revealed that there were two speedsters there the night Nora Allen was killed.  Perhaps it's leading to the Flashpoint event?  The concepts are strikingly similar.  The red lightning being future Flash fighting future Reverse-Flash, trying to save Nora?

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that he could be time-traveling frequently, relative to himself, rather than "at some point in the future".  That is, rather than "present Wells" talking to "future Wells" in that scene, it could be a case of playing out the scene as Wells in the afternoon, and then later that evening jumping back and being the Reverse Flash.  Given that Wells has the suit and obviously knows about the future, there's no reason to think he isn't the Reverse Flash right now.

Comment: @Robert Welp, I was wrong.

Comment: Lol, I'm still gonna give you credit for the answer. I dunno about anyone else, but I geeked out this episode, hard. Especially at the end.  Technically,  you were right though.  He was moving fast enough to make it look like there were two of him.